# record Created By

Tags: data-loader, migration, data-migration

I have migrated 50k records in `Case` object and nearly 500k records in custom objects in Production org. After going soft launch i realized I did't updated the `Created By` from the older system. I want to know is there any way to update the `Created By` values. One way what i know is extract the record from Salesforce update the value and insert the record. My problem is Users have started using the system.

Is there any workaround to update the `Created By` value without affecting user?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to contact salesforce support team. They can enable editing in audit fields(Created Date etc) for you. Once they have enabled it, you can update created dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *update* those records. You can either choose to delete the records and start over, or deal with the fact that those dates are incorrect. The feature you're looking for is called [Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176484&language=en_US), and only allows you to insert artificial values, not update existing records with artificial values.